# Security in Ubuntu or Linux over all

Tags: security

I am just migrated from Windows to Ubuntu 16.04 - say a week ago.  I am not concerning about virus or malware since I don't downloaded stuff I am not sure about. In windows there are  off the shelves software such as anti key loggers, anti screen capture. I looked around and I couldn't find it for Linus OS.

Is Linux vulnerable to these key logger or screen capture ? How would I take step to prevent this ? Certainly I can not buy the software since there is no such tool for Linux. I have been looking for it on the web.

Please don't suggest me to go back to windows. I have seen things happened to me, and I want to get away from windows OS for good. Your opinions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A related article I found recently: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-easier-to-write-viruses-for-Windows-compared-to-OS-X-and-Linux/answer/Sax-zim-Bog

Comment: Your question may unfortunately be a little too broad for Ask Ubuntu....

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that anyone on here will suggest you go back to Windows!

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: You are at no risk.

Long answer: Most malware is written for Windows and cannot run on Linux.  It's the same reason why, for example, Adobe Photoshop won't run on Linux: the executable formats are totally different and you'd need a translation layer to run them (this is called "wine" and, honestly, if you can avoid it, avoid it).

One of the first habits you need to shake from your Windows background is to download software from the Internet.  You say, you don't do this, but I'm pretty sure you went to Mozilla to download Firefox when you were using Windows.  In Linux, we don't do this.  We use so called "repositories", basically, something like "software stores", except you don't have to pay and most if not all software is open source.  You access those with the commands `dpkg`, `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude` (really, depends on who is explaining you stuff) or the GUI version "Ubuntu Software".

Stick to what is in those repositories and you will be on the safest side of the Internet.  No need for resource hogging, closed source, anti-this and anti-that.  Even on Windows, those often are snake-oil, or even worse, malware themselves, not to mention they cost money.

Welcome to freedom, welcome to Ubuntu.